# Deploy Blazor Server App in Azure WebApp completed but empty folder

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I need your help!

I have an application in Blazor server and I'm trying to integrate a publish pipiline to Azure DevOps.
The publication takes place on a Linux-type Azure WebApp in a staging distribution slot.

My pipeline completes successfully, I checked the .zip file in my agent folder and it seems to be correct (the dll and the wwwroot folder are in the root).
I'm attaching the pipeline I'm currently using.

One thing I've noticed is that in the Distribution Center tab, of my App Service, the Source Branch is Main instead of Staging.
I state that I created the app and the staging slot manually and there was no association with an external repository.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzlZQ.png)

```
trigger:
  - staging

pool:
  Default

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')]

steps:
- script: |
    dotnet restore
    dotnet build --configuration Release
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: 'Company.Frontend/Company.Frontend.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
    
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
 

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 5
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'CompanyStg'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: 'xxx-app-stg'
    projects: 'Company.Frontend/Company.Frontend.csproj'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'Company-STG'
    SlotName: 'staging'
    packages: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*.zip'
```

I tried publishing via visual studio and the application is successfully deployed

Comment: Pls open the kudu site, url should like(https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.com/newui), and share the screenshot if the files under `wwwroot`.

Comment: By the way, pls open this site and let us check the home page, we need to confirm the issue by the error code or message. And you also need to share the [`Startup Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#built-in-images) for us.  If the setting not been set, you should add it for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline looks fine but I'd try troubleshooting by making those changes:

1. I looked up my pipelines and my trigger looks something like this:

```
trigger: 
  branches:
    include: 
    - develop
    - qa
    - staging
```

2. You can try adding `--self-contained` to arguments in `DotNetCoreCLI@2`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output --self-contained true --runtime linux-x64'
    projects: 'Company.Frontend/Company.Frontend.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

3. I'd try and change the `AzureWebApp@1` to just use the zip file, made in `ArchiveFiles` and remove the csproj bit:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 5
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'CompanyStg'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: 'xxx-app-stg'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'Company-STG'
    SlotName: 'staging'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

4. Also, something that bit me in the ass before - make sure your staging branch has this version of `YAML` file. I spent too many hours troubleshooting before only to realise my YAML file was on `develop` and not on `qa` or `staging`.

Comment: No problem, which part was the culprit out of curiosity?